# Excel - leave blank if reference cell is blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that uses following formula to calculate +357 to display "NO" or "YES"

`=IF(AND(TODAY()<M3+357),"NO","YES")`

My problem is; I want this cell to display nothing when the reference "M3" cell is blank.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest another IF:

This should do what you are looking for:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(M3),"",IF(AND(TODAY()<M3+357),"NO","YES")
```