# How check if 2 cell are blank with If / or formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i use this formula

```
=IF(OR(J2={"F";"S";"P"});Inventaire!D14; IF(OR(J2={"Mat.IN";"Mat.OUT"}); Inv.Materiel!D14; ""))
```

but it only refer to J2 if blank
i want to add if Inventaire!D14 is blank to "" don't show 0

is there anyway to check if 2 cell are blank at same time ?

thanks for your help

Comment: Would using `ISBLANK` function as indicated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525663/excel-leave-blank-if-reference-cell-is-blank?rq=1) work for you? In general though, it would help if you would rephrase your question, it's a bit tough to understand.

Comment: Also, could you give us a specific example of what you want your function to put in and put out?

Comment: sorry i dont catch it

Comment: =if(or(J2={"F";"S";"P"});if(and(isblank(Inventaire!D16;"";Inventaire!D16)))

Comment: i want to check if J2 is ok the if cell on Inventaire!D16 is ok then display

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap your output in another if statement to check if the result is empty, then output ""

```
=IF(ISBLANK(IF(OR(J2={"F";"S";"P"}),Inventaire!D14:IF(OR(J2={"Mat.IN";"Mat.OUT"}),Inv.Materiel!D14,""))),"",IF(OR(J2={"F";"S";"P"}),Inventaire!D14:IF(OR(J2={"Mat.IN";"Mat.OUT"}),Inv.Materiel!D14,"")))
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if two cells are blank, use this code:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B3),ISBLANK(C3)), 1, 0)
```

Above, is cells `C3` and `B3` are blank, the function will return `1`. If either or both have values, it'll return a `0`. Hope this helps. I'm not sure how you incorporate this into your own function.

Comment: =SI(ET(J2="";Inventaire!D16="");"";SI(OU(J2={"F";"S";"P"});Inventaire!D14; SI(OU(J2={"Mat.IN";"Mat.OUT"}); Inv.Materiel!D16; "")))